# how to get an administrative_area_level_1 list for a given country from google maps api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a drill down interactive map
I want to use lists, that will enable the user to drill from continent to country to administrative_area_level_1 regions

is there a way to query google maps api and get a list of administrative_area_level_1 names for a given country?

I looked in geocoding - which gives me essentially a lat/lng coordinates for an address
also looked at reverse geocoding, that will return address components for a given lat/lng

not relevant...
i need a list of administrative_area_level_1 names for a given country...

Comment: I need similar but for administrative area 1. It seems there's no way to get those lists.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe Google has a complete list or API for that information, but there are several resources that might be helpful:

[Counties](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=0IMZAFCwR-t7jZnVzaW9udGFibGVzOjIxMDIxNw) (US Census Data)

[Cities](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/cities-DMAregions) (Google AdWords API

["Geographical Targets"](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting) (Google AdWords API)

That last one is ambiguous but seems to include quite a lot. You could probably filter it down to just what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Google Maps API does no provide this functionality. You will have to look into solutions such as the [SimpleGeo Context API](https://simplegeo.com/products/context/#13.00/37.7724/-122.4058).